# Take the most recent value, which is not blank

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a task to create a column in a table visual in Power BI, which will always show the most recent value, regardless of what is selected in the date slicers.

Consider this dataset:

| Site | MonthYr | KPI Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alfa | 12/1/2023 | 100 |
| Alfa | 1/1/2024 | 99.6 |
| Alfa | 2/1/2024 |  |
| Beta | 12/1/2023 | 70 |
| Beta | 1/1/2024 |  |
| Beta | 2/1/2024 |  |
| Gama | 12/1/2023 | 60 |
| Gama | 1/1/2024 | 50 |

We have different sites, and their results for different KPIs.
The most recent value result for KPI 1 should be for site Alfa 99.6, for Beta - 70, and for Gama - 50, even if they are for different months.

Currently, I have a measure, which takes the last value - for Feb.2024, but it has some blanks in it. I want to check for the last non-blank value, even if it was like 6 months ago.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a measure like below-

```
max_kpi = 

VAR max_date = 
CALCULATE(
    max(table_name[MonthYr]),
    FIlter(
        ALLEXCEPT(table_name,table_name[Site]),
        NOT ISBLANK( table_name[KPI Value])
    )
)

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(table_name[KPI Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(table_name,table_name[Site]),
        table_name[MonthYr] = max_date
    )
)
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use LASTNONBLANKVALUE() as shown in the examples here.

https://dax.guide/lastnonblankvalue/

Comment: Yes, that works fine, but the year still continues to filter the data. If I use the dataset above, when 2024 is selected lastnonblankvalue for Beta is blank still. I tried to implement ALL(Dim Date), but that did not work.